# the result is diiferent when using supervisorJob() although there is no error

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm studying coroutine now.
Testing the supervisorJob(), I found some incomprehensible situation.
When I use the supervisorJob() and not use, the result is different although there is no error.

```
fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    launch(SupervisorJob()) {
        launch {
            println("Launch A")
            launch {
                println("Launch B")
            }
        }

        launch {
            println("Launch A End")
        }
    }
}
```

*The result When using supervisorJob()*

```
Launch A
Launch B
Launch A End
```

*Not using supervisorJob()*

```
Launch A
Launch A End
Launch B
```

I don't understand this difference, Why does the supervisorJob() change the result?

Comment: Are you sure the difference is in the `SupervisorJob`? Async code like this can run in any order, unless you make parts of it wait for other parts. In this case, "Launch B" will always be printed after "Launch A", but everything else could theoretically occur in any order.

Comment: Yes I understand the result can run in any order, But I tried this codes at 10 times more, and results are same.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. But also just an implementation detail, and might be different if you run it on another machine, another JVM or JVM version, or at another time.

Comment: So do you think this results would be diiferent according to JVM? Also I tested this on kotlin playground web site, and got same result like above.

Comment: Even if you get the same results every single time, it doesn't matter. The order of "Launch A end" vs "Launch B" is _unspecified_. This means it can be one way 50% of the time or 100% of the time, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a race condition. There's no defined/guaranteed order that these different print statements will execute. It may be the same result the vast majority of the time because the same code is being run on the same device, and then when you change something that causes a slight difference in amount of processing, it tips over to the other outcome being more likely. But either way, the order is not guaranteed.